# mongodb replicaset

Tags: replication, mongodb

I am adding a new member in ReplicaSet and it starts initial sync bur after certain point sync break and start resync again.this process continue and never complete its initial sync.so please resolve this issue.

Below are the LOG file Error messages

```
Mon Jul 21 18:25:42.628 [rsSync] oplog sync 1 of 3
Mon Jul 21 18:25:42.632 [rsSync] Socket say send() errno:110 Connection timed out xx.xxx.xxx.xx:27017
Mon Jul 21 18:25:42.638 [rsSync] connection lost to mongo2.applect.com:27017; is your tcp keepalive interval set appropriately?replSet initial sync exception: 9001 socket exception [5] server [xxxxxx.xxxxxx.com:27017] 7 attempts remaining
```

Comment: Can you share this value: cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time

Comment: 300. at first it was 7200 then that time the same problem happen and right now i  have changes to 300 but still facing same problem

Comment: is your network trustworthy? is it possible to missing packets?

Comment: which parameter should i check for network.and how can i judge of missing packets

Comment: A continuous ping from the one host to another can tell you that